# Ruby won't divide string

Tags: ruby

I am trying to divide a user-input age by 2. My code is below:

```
puts "what is your name?"
name = gets.chomp

puts "when were you born please enter your birthdate"
birthdate = gets.chomp

puts "how old are you "
age = gets.chomp

puts "hello"  + name + " wow that is a good day to be born" + "thats a great age"
puts "the half  of your age is" + age/2 + " that is good to know"
```

It does not work.

Comment: I am no ruby developer, but there are a few things to consider. First of all, is age being considered a number or a string? It is possible that it is handling the age variable as a string and not a number. Another option is that  "+age/2 +..." is adding age to the string and then dividing the string by 2 (doing weird order of operations stuff due to the nature of string concatenation).

Comment: You should add the error you're getting. Assuming you want a number and not a string but it's hard to be certain without an error message.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `age` is a string

```
age = gets.to_i
```

Now it's a number. But you can't concatenate a string and a number. Two options:

interpolation

```
puts "the half  of your age is #{age/2} that is good to know"
```

or

```
puts "the half  of your age is " + (age/2).to_s + " that is good to know"
```

Comment: Keep in mind that because both numerator and denominator are integers, the code described in this answer will always show half the age as an integer. So if your age is 31, for example, it will report that half your age is 15. If you want to show partial years, change it to "Half of your age is #{age / 2.0}. That is good to know."

Comment: Yep, you're definitely right. My answer just aimed to make the user aware why its code doesn't work

Comment: Thank you all for the assistance